# Mutation of Captured Var 'value' in Concurrently-Executing Code

Tags: ios, swift, async-await

I am using **async await** in my functions but getting error while using it.

My code is:

```
class DatabaseManager {

   func storeValOnDB(value: String) async -> Bool {

     do {
            
            let finish = try await self.database.child("Values").setValue(value)
            print(finish)
            return true
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

And I am using this in my **View Model** function:

```
func storeValue() {

    var foo = ""

    Task {
   
         let result = await DatabaseManager.shared.storeValOnDB(value: self.value)

         switch result {
                            
           case true:
                            
              foo = value  // Mutation of captured var 'convos' in concurrently-executing code
           case false:
               print("failed to store value")
        }
    }
}
```

When I am **assigning** some value inside the **Task** but it gives me the error.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and of course show a minimal example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: The code inside your `Task` executes asynchronously and you are attempting to capture the local variable `foo` from outside of that asynchronous block. You can't do that. It is indeterminate as to when the `foo = value` assignment will take place. It depends on how long it takes for the database operation to complete. If the assignment was permitted then you could get different results for different executions of your app depending on when the asynchronous work completes. Perhaps [edit] your question to explain what you are trying to do. Probably you just need to move code into the `Task`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't access mutable values in the task declared outside of your task.
If you need to pass back a data from the task you could use task's return value.

In order to let the task to return a value you need to specify that when creating a task. So the `storeValue` function could be refactored to this:

```swift
func storeValue() async {
    var foo = ""
    var valueToStore = "value"
    let t = Task<String, Never> { [valueToStore] in
        let result = await DatabaseManager.shared.storeValOnDB(value: valueToStore)
        switch result {
        case true:
            return "some new value \(foo)"
        case false:
            print("failed to store value")
            return ""
        }
    }
    foo = await t.value
}
```

In the code above `Task<String, Never>` means the task returns a string and doesn't throw an error.
Note that we don't access self.value in the task anymore, instead we use capture list and define `[valueToStore]` so that the value of the valueToStore is copied to the task. In this case we avoid any memory issue that could occur when you access/modify a variable from multiple threads.

Additionally you should use error throwing mechanism instead of returning a boolean in the `storeValOnDB` function. Let's imagine that `storeValOnDB` is defined like this:

```swift
func storeValOnDB(value: String) async throws
```

So if the value couldn't be stored it will throw an error, otherwise it won't return any value. This is greatly simplifies our code. Now that the task code is much shorter and easy to read we could omit optional generic declaration (`<>`) as well:

```swift
func storeValue() async {
    var foo = ""
    var valueToStore = "value"
    let t = Task { [valueToStore] in
        try await DatabaseManager.shared.storeValOnDB(value: valueToStore)
        return "some new value"
    }
    do {
        foo = try await t.value
    } catch {
        print("failed to store value: \(error)")
    }
}
```